# MetronicApp Angular service

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to use Angular services with the Metronic App. I have specified my service as this:

```
angular.module('MetronicApp').service('shaperService', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.shapers = function(params)
{
    return $http.get('http://serviceurl.app', {
        params : params
    });
}
}]);
```

---

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('MetronicApp').controller('ShapersController', ['shaperService', function (shaperService, $rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    App.initAjax(); // initialize core components
    Layout.setSidebarMenuActiveLink('set', $('#sidebar_menu_link_profile'));
    $scope.shaper = shaperService.shapers;
    $scope.fname = "Jason";// set profile link active in sidebar menu
    $scope.lname = "Kane";// set profile link active in sidebar menu
    $scope.name = $scope.fname + " " + $scope.lname;// set profile link active in sidebar menu
});

// set sidebar closed and body solid layout mode
$rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid = true;
$rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed = true;
}]);
```

However, when I run the page, I get

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=httpProvider%20%3C-%20http%20%3C.
```

This seems to be an injection error. My question is, how can I inject my service into my controller?

Thanks

Comment: Bad typing, 'http', it's '$http', the first line of your service.

Comment: Not the issue here. That syntax is not complaining.

Comment: Did you change that `http` to `$http`? Because that's the error that Angular marks.

Comment: I did. That error was resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. The service was not initiated. You can initiate the service like this.

```
angular.module('MetronicApp').factory('shaperService', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.shapers = function(params)
{
    return $http.get('http://serviceurl.app', {
    params : params
    });
}
}]);
```